# Can we just divide $f(x)$ into $1/n$ in Real Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In the below picture, we divide the value of $f$ into $1/2^n$. Can we just divide it into $1/n$? For example,
$$A_{in}=\{x: i/n\le f(x)< (i+1)/n\}?
$$
Is any difference?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $$A_{in} =\left\{ x: \frac{i}{n}\leq f(x) <\frac{i+1}{n}\right\}$$
then for $f:[0,1]\to [0,1],$ $f(x)=x$ you obtain
$$s_2 (x) =\frac{1}{2}\chi_{[2^{-1} ,1 )} (x) +\chi_{\{1\}} (x)$$
$$s_3 (x) =\frac{1}{3}\chi_{[3^{-1},2\cdot3^{-1} )} (x) +\frac{2}{3}\chi_{[2\cdot3^{-1},1 )} (x)+\chi_{\{1\}} (x)$$

so $$s_2 (2^{-1} ) =2^{-1}>3^{-1} =s_3 (2^{-1} )$$

so you obtain a sequence $s_1 , s_2 , ...$ which need not to be monotone increasing.